# Return data from WCF Service as list without any custom Class

Tags: wcf

I want to get data from WCF service as list. Below are some prerequisites

1. Table name will be passed as runtime.
2. No model class or custom class need to be required
3. Application should return data as list
4. Can create class at runtime

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please have a look at [Ho do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then please edit your question

Comment: So what's your question actually?